# O que significa IoT no contexto do desenvolvimento?

Tags: terminologia, iot

Hoje só se fala em Internet of Things. Entendo que isso é o uso da internet em dispositivos diversos. A ideia é que qualquer objeto pode se conectar à internet e se beneficiar disto. Obviamente que todo objeto IoT tem uma capacidade computacional.

Está só relacionada à internet? Não é IoT se não está conectado a internet? Se não é como se chama um objeto computacional sem internet?

Para o desenvolvedor o que importa o IoT? Muda alguma coisa no desenvolvimento?

Se souber especificamente, C#, .NET está preparado para isto?

Comment: Para quem não sabe, o Claudenir é o cara em IoT no Brasil :)

Comment: Ótima pergunta com uma boa resposta. Vou dar aqui só uma dica de dar uma olhada em [Sistemas Embarcados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_embarcado). Sendo bem simplista IoT é um sistema embarcado que é capaz de se conectar à internet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A pergunta é ótima. Não há como falar de IoT sem falar de internet, um projeto de IoT sem internet não é IoT, torna-se na verdade um processo automatizado. Esta é a principal diferença de IoT e automação.

IoT é uma sigla nova, mas um ação antiga. desde 1990 já se fazia IoT na indústria e monitoramento de veículos por exemplo, onde o veículo passa a ser “Things” que está sendo monitorada. Por isso eu tenho uma definição minha  para IoT:

> Qualquer coisa, objeto, material, que com um dispositivo inteligente você consiga, comandá-lo remotamente (ligar, desligar, executar funções), ou que seja possível executar um destes verbos: Comandar, Telemetrar, Gerenciar, Medir

#### O que isso muda no contexto do desenvolvimento?

Depende de qual contexto você deseja atuar em sua arquitetura de hardware que você irá usar. Se sou programador em C# e vou usar uma placa de monitoramento onde o desenvolvimento é em C, o contexto do desenvolvimento pode mudar radicalmente, tenho que aprender uma linguagem nova, um *mind-set* novo de programação, não tenho *framework* para gerenciar, é *unmanage code*. Se uso placas que suportam C# e seu *framework* é 50% do caminho traçado, os outros 50% são as novas classes/objetos para acesso a toda parte digital (True/False) e analógica (receber dados e informações).

No contexto de conhecimento geral e lógica, te afirmo que conhecimentos em eletrônica agregam e muito no processo. Não tenha dúvida. no contexto de usar C# para IOT, tenho uma [palestra gravada que mostra o “HelloWord” com .NET MicroframeWork com Netduino  (Arduino rodando .NET)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HacvAT2IWg).

Agora sendo mais *abusado* se vou usar uma [LattePanda](http://lattepanda.com) não muda quase nada, pois é uma *miniboard* computacional 100% compatível e posso até usar Delph7 o VB6 em meu projeto e IoT. Seria abusado, mas é um fato.

Pra finalizar. Tudo isso e Placa de Prototipação. Fazer produto *REAL* e escalável com estas placas, não é o caminho. o Caminho é ao final de sua prototipação, *bater* sua placa ou usar produtos de mercado que permitam o mesmo desenvolvimento realizado em sua prototipação. [Um exemplo de Modem com Placa analógica e digital criado pra IoT e que você programa em Java por exemplo é este produto profissional](http://www.desenvolvedoresdaruma.com.br/sddn/ddcmkt/ddcmkt_011_11.html).

Answer (score 4):

[image: ioT]

Da mesma maneira que dividimos a evolução da indústria em grandes revoluções, também podemos segmentar a evolução da tecnologia. As revoluções industriais foram marcadas pelas grandes mudanças no sistema de trabalho. Já as revoluções tecnológicas marcaram as mudanças na forma como interagimos e nos relacionamos com as máquinas e outros seres humanos.

A primeira revolução tecnológica aconteceu na criação de uma rede de computadores, hoje conhecida como internet (**♥**). Essa rede que surge para ser um meio de comunicação seguro durante o período da guerra fria, ganha força, espaço e provoca uma mudança radical no mundo.

Com a evolução e expansão da internet, as pessoas descobriram novas maneiras de interagir com o mundo. Através desse canal passamos a ver de outras maneiras as formas de comunicação e consumo. Optando, cada vez mais, pelo contato remoto, principalmente quando se trata de transações financeiras e compras.

Naturalmente, esse processo também evoluiu, e estamos chamando o próximo passo de **IoT** (**Internet of Things**. Em português: **Internet das Coisas**). Ou seja, é a próxima revolução tecnológica e tem como objetivo conectar pessoas e dispositivos variados através do uso da internet, de sensores e equipamentos.

A ideia é que cada objeto que utilizamos permita que seja realizada uma coleta de dados sobre o seu consumo, a fim de proporcionar uma experiência melhor por meio da análise desses dados. Para que esses objetos e dados se conversem, é necessária a criação de novos sensores, desenvolvimento da nanotecnologia e da inteligência artificial.

**Internet das Coisas e nossas vidas**
A intenção da **Internet das Coisas (IoT)** não é impactar radicalmente no cotidiano das pessoas. Eu diria que é exatamente o contrário! O objetivo é que a tecnologia seja incorporada ao nosso dia a dia de maneira natural. Fazendo, sim, pequenas mudanças, mas sem que notemos imediatamente essas alterações.

A tecnologia se tornará simples e interativa, até que a utilizemos de forma intuitiva. Ao ponto de não precisarmos ler um manual para utilizar um celular ou uma geladeira que realiza compras pela internet.

Mas, nesse sentido, é fundamental que as aplicações e funcionalidades desses dispositivos inteligentes possuam uma interface simples, de fácil navegação e possibilitem uma experiência, de fato, intuitiva e agradável aos usuários

> **O que são essas “coisas”?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, você deve ter entendido que esse tipo de tecnologia tem a ver com “**coisas**” que fazem parte da nossa rotina. Mas o quão profundamente podemos imaginar essas coisas? Exatamente assim, todas as coisas! Desde que possuam conectividade, os hardwares podem ser empregados em qualquer objeto para que comecem a coletar, analisar e transmitir dados.

Quer um exemplo mais prático? No segmento de cidades urbanas, por exemplo, já é possível encontrar tecnologias como rastreadores e sistemas que gerenciam o tráfego de uma cidade.

Outro exemplo? Dê um **Google** e *leia sobre* a linha de dispositivos **SMART (Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology, em português tecnologia de auto-monitoramento, análise e relatório)**, eles se comunicam pela rede e facilitam as ‘tarefas do lar’. Por exemplo, a temperatura da colcha varia de acordo com a sua respiração e frequência cardíaca. Além disso, há a possibilidade de adequar a iluminação do ambiente e umidade do ar, tudo através do mesmo aplicativo.

> **Mas como posso fazer parte da IoT?**

**IoT** é um **segmento multidisciplinar**, que precisa do somatório de várias áreas da TI para se tornar aplicável. E possui, ainda, um potencial enorme de crescimento.

Então, se você não simpatiza com **Java**, **banco de dados** ou **front-end**, **não se preocupe!** **Existem outras possibilidades**. **Python**, por **exemplo**, é uma linguagem amplamente utilizada nas soluções de **análise de dados (data analytics)** e **machine learning**. **Machine Learning**? Isso, **aprendizado de máquina**! É um método que automatiza modelos de análise de dados e vem se desenvolvendo juntamente com a *inteligência artificial*. Em outras palavras, permite tratar um grande volume de dados, enquanto seu programa evolui com o tempo de forma autônoma.

Lembra do **J.A.R.V.I.S**, o sistema que tanto auxilia o **Homem de Ferro?** Pois bem, apresento-lhe então o **“Just Rather Very Intelligent System”** (em português, só um sistema muito inteligente). **Caso queira saber mais**, procure pelo **Watson** no **Google**, o **ilustre** funcionário **robô** da **IBM**.

**Mas relaxa**, **você não precisa** ser um *expert* da **inteligência artificial** para trabalhar com dados. A **área de cloud computing** tem crescido de forma exponencial nos últimos anos. Afinal, é quase impossível alguém ter seu próprio espaço para armazenar todos os dados coletados de todos os sensores e dispositivos espalhados pelo ambiente que será observado.

**Bom, chega né?** Como você deve ter notado, existe uma longa caminhada no desenvolvimento de softwares de *IoT* e uma infinidade de caminhos que você pode escolher para fazer parte disso. **O foco é conectar pessoas e máquinas, #fikdik de mercado. Te adianta e vai atrás dos teus objetivos!**