# Qualquer linguagem de programação usa memória?

Tags: memória, independente-de-linguagem

Quando eu escrevo um programa em qualquer linguagem de programação, compiladas ou interpretadas, é necessário uma RAM para executar? Por favor explique.

Sendo mais específica, fiz um editor de texto usando JavaScript. Quando esse editor de texto é executado no JavaScript, o que acontece? Isso vai direto para a memória ou vai direto para o processador?

Pois se temos o código fonte de algum programa, é de se imaginar que esse código fonte de alguma maneira é livre, não depende do sistema operacional e sim da linguagem que foi escrita.

Em virtude disto, um código fonte + linguagem de programação, não precisaria, ou não teria necessariamente algum tipo de armazenamento, para tal feito. Isto é, de tanto faz compilar ou interpretar, é o mesmo. Se você compila, de alguma forma faz com que haja uma interpretação o mesmo acontece com interpretadores. E não necessitaria de RAM também.

Comment: Nem nós existimos sem memória... :(

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/64969

Comment: Se não me falha a memória, para que qualquer programa seja executado ele deve ser carregado na memória do computador. Memória RAM é usada pelo processador para armazenar os arquivos e programas que estão sendo processados. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 14):

> Quando eu escrevo um programa em qualquer linguagem de programação, compiladas ou interpretadas, é necessário uma RAM para executar?

## Teoria

[Toda linguagem de programação precisa ser Turing Complete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), caso contrário ela não pode receber esta denominação. Isso significa que toda linguagem de programação, entre outras características, precisa ter um meio de armazenar dados e isso é feito em memória.

Qual tipo de memória? Isso não é especificado. Então na teoria não precisam ser RAM.

Em geral um programa precisa estar em memória para ser executado. Novamente não precisa ser RAM.

## Prática

A memória usada para conter o programa ou armazenar dados de sua execução é a RAM. Seria difícil fazer diferente, pelo menos em [arquitetura Von Neumann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189180/101). Claro que poderia usar uma memória secundária, de massa, como um disco, mas a performance sofreria muito.

De fato, quando há mais dados do que memória RAM disponível é comum que parte deles sejam colocados em memória de massa, mas no momento do uso sempre precisa estar na RAM, e o sistema operacional deve gerenciar isto, provavelmente através de [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207174/101).

> Sendo mais específica, fiz um editor de texto usando JavaScript. Quando esse editor de texto é executado no JavaScript, o que acontece?

Sobre o [carregamento e execução da programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/101) já foi respondido. Também [como o computador entende o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

Mas em JavaScript é um pouco diferente. Ele recebe o código fonte e precisa [interpretá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101) ou [compilá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). Na verdade, quase todo mecanismo de JavaScript é [JITtado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Então há um processo de transformação do fonte em código binário. Tudo isto é feito por um software, então só esse processo já usa muita memória, para armazenar o fonte, os passos intermediários e o resultado final binário que será executado. Claro que toda essa memória vai sendo liberada conforme o uso, se tudo correr bem e o código do JITTer for bem-feito, como costuma ser.

> Isso vai direto para a memória ou vai direto para o processador?

O processador possui apenas registradores limitados, mesmo os mais poderosos ficam na casa das dezenas ou centenas, cada um podendo ocupar uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101). Então é virtualmente impossível trabalhar só com o processador. Não importa o tipo de linguagem. Claro que no momento exato da execução de uma operação o dado em questão estará no registrador, não pode operar direto na RAM.

Imagine que tem um problema muito complexo para resolver na mão, como faz? Vai executando cada passo e cada resultado vai sendo escrito em papéis para poder usar depois, certo? No computador isso é RAM. Quando está fazendo uma conta, manipulando algo é comum fazer um cálculo intermediário totalmente descartável, isto é feito em RAM, mas depois é jogado fora. Alguma coisa é tão simples que você faz de cabeça, isto é o processador usando registradores.

Então, sim, **qualquer tipo de linguagem precisa de RAM para manter seus dados**.

> Pois se temos o código fonte de algum programa, é de se imaginar que esse código fonte de alguma maneira é livre, não depende do sistema operacional e sim da linguagem que foi escrita.

Sim, mas não vejo relevância neste contexto. Pelo menos isso parece fazer pouco sentido ao que foi perguntado. Código algum tem relevância para o sistema operacional.

> Em virtude disto, um código fonte + linguagem de programação, não precisaria, ou não teria necessariamente algum tipo de armazenamento, para tal feito.

Não, como já demonstrado.

> Isto é, de tanto faz compilar ou interpretar, é o mesmo. Se você compila, de alguma forma faz com que haja uma interpretação o mesmo acontece com interpretadores.

É, mas não vejo o que isso tem a ver com o contexto apresentado na pergunta. A frase final nem faz muito sentido.

> E não necessitaria de RAM também.

Não consigo imaginar porque não necessitaria. Acho que lendo esta resposta e todos os *links* apresentados entenda que precisa sim. Precisa para o fonte, para o binário, para os dados, e estou falando só o uso direto do programa, nem do entorno dele que precisa também.

Também deve ser de interesse:

- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101)
- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu costumo ter cuidado com palavras fortes como *todas*. Nem toda linguagem de programação é turing-completa. É verdade que não existe linguagem não-turing completa de largo emprego comercial, mas existem linguagens funcionais como *Charity* que não são turing-complete.

Comment: @Renan Toda linguagem de programação é *turing complete* por definição. Se uma linguagem se autodenomina, ou popularmente as pessoas denominam fora da definição ela precisa justificar isso, mesmo assim não quer dizer que seja. Como não conheço a linguagem e de onde está tirando sua definição, não posso falar nada.