# Manipulação do malloc() e realloc()

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Ainda não me sinto completamente confiante quanto ao uso do `malloc()` ou `realloc()`, estas duas maneiras são equivalentes?

#### 1)

```
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    char *s2,*s1;
    s1=NULL;
    s2=malloc(200);

    while(x++<3)
    {
        scanf(" %s", s2);
        s1=realloc(s1, strlen(s2));
        strcpy(s1, s2);
        printf("%s\n", s1);
    }

    free(s1);
    free(s2);
}
```

ou fazendo

#### 2)

```
 while(x++<3)
    {
        scanf(" %s", s2);
        s1=malloc(strlen(s2));
        strcpy(s1, s2);
        printf("%s\n", s1);
        free(s1);
    }
```

O que aconteceria na memoria ao fazermos duas vezes o malloc, como assim:

```
    int x=0;
    char *s2,*s1;
    s1=malloc(100); /*reservar aqui*/
    s2=malloc(200);

    while(x++<3)
    {
        scanf(" %s", s2);
        s1=malloc(strlen(s2)); /*e reservar aqui*/
        strcpy(s1, s2);
        printf("%s\n", s1);
        free(s1);
    }
```

Há alguma maneira de reservar o espaço de memoria desta forma? Só mesmo alocando um espaço de 200 (como por exemplo) e só depois realojar exatamente a memoria necessária?

```
    scanf(" %s", s2);
    s2=malloc(strlen(s2));
```

O que realmente faz um `malloc()` e `realloc()` internamente na memoria?

Comment: Mas qual era o objetivo dos `whiles` ? É que eu vejo `strcpy` quando suspeito que a intenção era `strcat`, caso contrário a realocação em quase todos os casos não seria necessária. O objetivo é ler palavra a palavra e ir juntando numa `string` ?

Comment: É apenas um pequeno codigo para expor a minha duvida sobre a alocaçao de memoria, apenas para entender o funcionamento do malloc() e realloc(), este codigo apenas tem finalidade de ser usado para aprender sobre alocaçao de memoria

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definições de `malloc` e `realloc`:

**malloc**:

Esse método aloca um espaço no *heap* que não tenha sido inicializado, tem como retorno um ponteiro para a memoria alocada. A assinatura da função é:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Onde size_t corresponde ao tipo de dados integral retornado pelo operador `sizeof` e é usado para representar o tamanho (em bytes) de um objeto. Ele é definido (no cabeçalho string.h na linguagem C e no cabeçalho em C ++) como um tipo integral não assinado. É apenas uma indicação de que o tipo é usado para conter o número de bytes de memória (e não o usual *unsigned int*).

O código abaixo aloca memória para 10 inteiros e designa o endereço da memória alocada (endereço do primeiro *byte* da memória) para o ponteiro de `int ptr`:

```
int * ptr = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

- Se o sistema não for capaz de alocar o espaço necessário no `heap` então a função retornará `null`.
- Se o tamanho for zero  `(malloc(0))`, então a função pode retornar tanto `null` como um ponteiro valido.
- De *default* a função retorna um ponteiro do tipo *void* que precisa ser devidamente *castado* antes de utilizar( no exemplo acima nos utilizamos `int*` para fazer o *casting*).
- A memoria retornada pela função não é inicializada e contem valores "lixo".

**realloc**:

Esse método muda o tamanho do bloco de memoria no heap. Suponha um ponteiro ( digamos `ptr`) que está apontando um espaço na memoria definido por um `malloc`, como o que fizemos na explicação de *malloc*. E você quer aumentar o tamanho to espaço de memoria apontado por `ptr` de 10 para 20, sem perder o conteúdo já alocado em memoria. Nesse caso você pode usar o `realloc`. A assinatura da função é:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

Onde `ptr` é o ponteiro para o bloco alocado, e `size` é o novo tamanho (em bytes) para o novo bloco de memoria. é possível que a função vai mover o bloco de memoria para um outro lugar caso não seja capaz de alocar o espaço logo depois de onde já está. Nesse caso vai alocar um espaço de 20 inteiros em outro lugar e copiar o conteúdo contido pelo bloco de 10 inteiros de tamanho. E assim o valor de `ptr` vai mudar.

**CUIDADOS A SEREM TOMADOS:**

```
int * ptr1 = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
int * ptr2 = ptr1;
ptr2 = (int*) realloc(ptr2, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

Quando `realloc` é chamado, a localização de memória apontada por ambos os ponteiros pode ser desalocada (no caso de o espaço contíguo não estar disponível logo após o bloco de memória). `ptr2` agora apontará para o local recém-deslocado no `heap` (retornado por *realloc*), mas `ptr1` ainda está apontando para o local antigo (que agora é desalocado).

**PS:**

Para a `realloc` o primeiro parâmetro para a função pode ser tanto um ponteiro para um bloco de memoria que seu código estava utilizando ou pode ser `null pointer`, no segundo caso a função se comportará como um `malloc`

Comment: Espero que tenha esclarecido a sua duvida com essa explicação =)

Comment: Sim, está uma resposta bastante boa, muito obrigado. Vou deixar um tempinho só para dar mais alguma exposição a esta pergunta e depois valido uma resposta

Answer (score 6):

A resposta exata para isso depende de detalhe de implementação das funções de gerenciamento de memória, mas eu diria que em boa parte dos casos dá no mesmo. Há até quem só use `realloc()` usando um nulo como valor inicial.

O penúltimo código vazará a primeira alocação de `s1` porque sequer tem uma referência para ela depois que executa o miolo do código, nem que queria não pode liberar a memória ali. Claro, em um código simples assim, pouco importa, termina a execução e nada ruim acontece, mas feito isso no meio de um código enorme em produção e se é um padrão que se repete várias vezes pode criar problemas por largar alocações órfãs.

Note que nesse exemplo específico não precisa ficar alocando ou realocando, pode usar o mesmo espaço já que em seguida o valor é descartado. E mais ainda, seria melhor fazer alocação na *stack* e ter menos dor de cabeça. Entendo que seja só um exemplo isolado, mas é bom saber disso para depois não continuar reproduzindo-o em código real como uma boa prática equivocada.

Em código real em produção isto costuma ser feito diferentemente. É mais comum alocar um tamanho razoável na *stack* e só depois de ter o texto real é que irá copiar para o *heap* fazendo a alocação necessária já no tamanho adequado. Veja [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

[Cuidado com `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), seu uso em alguns casos pode causar mais estrago do que o foco da pergunta.

E já que a pergunta tem até uma recompensa, vamos aprender certo que não se deve fazer *cast* no `malloc()` em quase todas situações. Ele é menos legível, redundante, esconde certos tipos de erros entre outros problemas, vaja [Typecast do malloc é recomendável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123208/101) e [Qual a diferença nas sintaxe ptr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)) e ptr = malloc (sizeof(int))?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/101).

Documentação do [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) e [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

> Há alguma maneira de reservar o espaço de memoria desta forma? Só mesmo alocando um espaço de 200 (como por exemplo) e só depois realojar exatamente a memoria necessária?

Acho que isto deve responder: [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

> O que realmente faz um malloc() e realloc() internamente na memoria?

Depende do compilador ou até biblioteca que está usando, ou ainda da plataforma onde está rodando. Já sabendo o que é o *heap*, entenda que os algoritmos de alocação dele podem variar conforme a necessidade, e você pode fazer sua própria forma.

O mais comum é que esta função seja uma abstração que organiza a melhor forma de trabalhar em cada situação. Em geral ele invoca o sistema operacional para alocar uma região maior de memória que pode ser 4KB, ou, normalmente, múltiplos disto, em alguns casos 2MB ou 1GB, já que estes 3 são tamanhos de páginas de memória virtual comumente usados no sistema operacional. E conforme vai sendo pedido pela aplicação vai ocupando esses espaços. De certa forma é muito parecido com o *stack* que tem sua memória toda alocada e esperando para ser ocupada pelos *frames* de execução.

O problema se torna maior quando vai liberando espaços e depois ele tenta reusar estes espaços. Há um algoritmo que tenta ocupar esses espaços da melhor forma possível, o que é algo complicado conciliar tudo. Aí ocorre o que chamamos de fragmentação de memória e o algoritmo fica mais lento para fazer alocações, a não ser que o `free()` evite isso, o que ele será bem mais lento.

Seria bom ler mais em [Como o malloc() organiza a memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254358/101) e [As variáveis são alocadas aleatoriamente na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252011/101). Também será útil [Como o "free()" sabe quanto de memória tem que liberar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101) e [O que é page fault?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207174/101).

O `realloc()` é um `malloc()` que muda o tamanho alocado anteriormente. Um bom algoritmo tenta aumentar seu tamanho sem mudar a sua localização, mas nem sempre é possível, principalmente se está aumentando o tamanho. E se está diminuindo ou mudando o objeto de local é comum aumentar a fragmentação de memória. O local que sobrou ainda poderá ser reaproveitado, mas nem sempre será fácil colocar algo do tamanho adequado ali. E quando muda de lugar pode ficar distante de outro objeto que ele sempre está associado, o que diminui a localidade e suja o cache de memória. Portanto abusar dele pode causar estragos.

No fundo ambos são apenas manipuladores de uma estrutura de dados que organiza as alocações. E se você tem uma necessidade específica pode escrever uma estrutura e algoritmos que melhor se adapte para sua necessidade.

Fora isso a pergunta precisa ser mais específica sobre o que deseja.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se for possivel tente explicar de forma mais profunda como funcia a gestão de memoria, ou então cite alguns artigos para eu poder ler sobre este assunto, quero realmente aprender não de forma superficial. Todos os livros que li não acho um bom artigo para realmente perceber o que se passa na memoria.

Comment: Até posso, mas em uma pergunta sobre isto, esta é mais restrita. Na verdade se pesquisar, já respondi bastante sobre o assunto, boa parte já tem resposta, pergunte outras coisas específicas que não achar. Tem muita coisa pra falar, eu não tenho algo orgnanizado.