# Linguagem C: Como guardar informação no WHILE e apresentar os dados inseridos em uma lista?

Tags: c

**Eu gostaria de saber como faço para guardar os dados e apresenta-los no final; Ainda não fui ensinado a fazer isso. Como resolvo o item C da questão**

Considere que, para cada um dos hotéis fazenda da região, se tenha registrado o nome do hotel, a sua distância do centro da cidade (DA), o número médio de visitantes no último feriado (V) e o tipo de acesso ao hotel (AC sendo 0 – acesso não asfaltado; 1 – acesso asfaltado).
Construa um programa que leia esses dados e ao final informe:

a) O número de hotéis que distam mais de 15km do centro;

b) A quantidade média de visitantes no último feriado, nos hotéis com acesso não asfaltado;

c) O nome e a distância do centro em Km, de todos os hotéis de acesso asfaltado que tiveram menos de 1.000 visitantes.

Exemplo de entrada :

Hotel A, DA=10, V=100, AC=0

Hotel B, DA=20, V=50, AC=1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char hotel[20], w[1];
int V, AC, DA, centro=15, q1=0, q2=0, q3=0, q4;

printf("REGISTRO DE HOTEIS\n\n");

do{
    printf("\nHotel                      :");       scanf("%s",&hotel);
    printf("Distancia do centro em km    : ");      scanf("%d",&DA);
    printf("Visitantes no ultimo feriado : ");      scanf("%d",&V);
    printf("Acesso ao hotel\n Digite \n"
           "0 - acesso não asfaltado\n"
           "1 - acesso asfaltado         : ");      scanf("%d",&AC);

    if(DA>centro)
        q2++; //vai guardar quantos hoteis tem longe do centro

    if(AC==0){
        q1++;   //vai contar as repetições, nesse caso o numero de hoteis cadastrados
        q3 += V; //vai guardar todos os visitantes do ultimo feriado de todos os hoteis
    }
    if( V<1000 && AC==1)
        printf("\nHotel %s Distancia %d km. Asfaltado com menos de 1.000 visitantes.",hotel,DA);
        //c) O nome e a distância do centro em Km, 
        //de todos os hotéis de acesso asfaltado que tiveram menos de 1.000 visitantes.

    printf("\n\nNovo Registro S(sim) N(nao)? "); scanf("%s",w);

}while(strcmpi(w,"S")==0); //W = WHILE

q4 = q3/q1; //media de visitantes de todos os hoteis

/*c) O nome e a distância do centro em Km, 
de todos os hotéis de acesso asfaltado que tiveram menos de 1.000 visitantes.*/
if( V<1000 && AC==1)
    printf("\nHotel %s Distancia %d km. Asfaltado com menos de 1.000 visitantes.",hotel,DA);

//a) O número de hotéis que distam mais de 15km do centro;
printf("\nHoteis a 15km do centro                               : %d\n",q2);

//b) A quantidade média de visitantes no último feriado, nos hotéis com acesso não asfaltado;
printf("A media de visitantes nos hoteis com acesso sem asfalto : %d\n",q4);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em C uma string que contém um único caractere ocupa 2 posições: o próprio caractere e o caractere terminador '\0'. Se é apenas um caractere declare apenas `char w;`e no lugar de aspas duplas (") utilize aspas simples(') e compare diretamente: `w == 'S'` e utilie `%c`na leitura.
Não conheço a função `strcmpi` talvez seja `strcmp`.
Aqui: `scanf("%s",&hotel);` não tem este &: `scanf("%s", hotel);`.

Comment: codigo strcmpi é para aceitar tantos letras maiúsculas de minusculas. Muito obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, existem várias formas que você pudesse guardar os hotéis e apresentá-los no final, uma opção seria criar uma lista (estrutura de dados), mas pelo nível do exercício creio eu que seja uma implementação um pouco avançada pra ser utilizada como solução. Em minha opinião a forma de fazer isso da maneira mais simples possível seria usando um vetor, mas existem duas situações:

**1.** A quantidade de entradas do usuário é previamente conhecida, ou seja, se a questão tiver definido quantas entradas o usuário vai dar.

**2.** O usuário vai entrar com os hotéis até ele decidir parar.

Para o **1** você pode estabelecer esse limite n (quantidade de entradas) como o tamanho do vetor de hotéis e inicializá-lo,e ai, sempre dentro dessa condição:

```
 if( V<1000 && AC==1)
```

Você armazena o hotel em uma posição do vetor. Para isso você precisa de uma variável **i** para representar o índice.

No final vc cria um loop **for** que vai de **0 até i** e pronto.

Já para a **2**, você vai precisar trabalhar com alocação de memória, ou seja, você também irá criar um vetor, mas ele será criado com alocação dinâmica de memória, com um tamanho pré - estabelecido, que será realocado sempre que chegar no limite.

Para essa solução, sugiro da uma lida nesse tópico: [Manipulação do malloc() e realloc()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322228/manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-malloc-e-realloc)

Espero ter ajudado!

**Observações:** o scanf feito para o vetor char hotel não precisa do **&** já que de certa forma vc ta trabalhando com uma "string".

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada e tentar aprender.
No curso ainda estamos em sistema de repetição por isso eu acho que essa questão esta fugindo um pouco do que nos foi ensinado.