# O que são Zero Cost Abstractions?

Tags: terminologia, desempenho, rust, abstração

Estava lendo sobre Rust e vi que uma das vantagens dela é possuir Zero Cost Abstractions, gostaria de saber:

- O que são Zero Cost Abstractions?
- É algo que o programador precisa ter conhecimento para usar ou é indiferente?
- Realmente é um ponto 100% positivo? Não há nenhum efeito indesejável na utilização da linguagem por possuir esse recurso?

Comment: É o oposto do que o anda na moda em várias camadas, que é a ZiCA (Zillion cost abstraction™) - Exemplos: docker onde não precisa, uso de microserviços indiscriminadamente, aplicação "desktop" com Electron, "ERP" web, PDO, OOP em PHP, Laravel, RoR, jQuery pra tudo quanto é lado, e a lista vai longe...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que são Zero Cost Abstractions?

É a capacidade de se criar uma abstração, ter uma expressividade maior do que está fazendo, sem incorrer em custo por causa disto.

Em geral quando você cria uma abstração e esconde um detalhe de implementação costuma usar algum mecanismo que impõe algum custo de memória ou de processamento que nem sempre é perceptível, mas se medir ele está lá, e acumulando com outros em grande quantidade pode fazer a aplicação ser perceptivelmente menos eficiente.

É um objetivo nobre e eu gosto, mas é raro conseguir resultado efetivo.

## Origem do termo

É muito raro uma linguagem conseguir muitas boas abstrações sem custo algum. O que se faz é esse custo ser reduzido, ou ser óbvio, ou pagar só se usar a facilidade, mas ter uma forma de fazer, mesmo que mais complexa, sem o custo.

> What you don’t use, you don’t pay for. And further: What you do use, you couldn’t hand code any better.
>
> --Bjarne Stroustrup

A primeira frase da citação dá muita margem para muita coisa ser aceita como ZCA. A segunda mostra o lado mais difícil de obter.

O termo começou ser usado mais fortemente por C++ (dá para perceber pela citação acima do criador da linguagem), inclusive faz parte de sua filosofia. E marketing. Não estou querendo dizer que C++ não é eficiente e muitas vezes não atinja o objetivo de *zero cost abstraction*, mas ela atinge menos vezes do que faz parecer. Existem até artigos e palestras sobre o assunto, nem tudo é tão sem custo assim, mesmo comparando apenas com C.

Existem vários mecanismos de C++ que impõe custo e quando o lançam dizem que ele é sem custo. Em geral é muito eficiente, mas sem custo algum costuma ser exagero.

Por exemplo C, ela tem muitos recursos que podemos dizer que são abstrações de custo zero, isso se dá sempre que aquele código produz um Assembly exatamente igual você faria se tivesse que escrevê-lo na mão e com capacidade de fazer o mais otimizado possível. Se não conseguir, se colocar uma instrução a mais, se precisar ocupar algum espaço a mais, se tiver que optar por uma instrução que custe mais caro, se a ordem necessária for uma que não privilegie otimizações do processador no momento da execução, então o custo de abstração não foi zero.

Já vi definição que diz que o significado seria:

> os custos são bem definidos, previsíveis e mais ou menos controláveis

Isso é uma falácia. Mesmo quando você considera que apenas poder enxergar o custo que pagará já é ZCA ainda é muito complicado, vou citar exemplos que os custos não são tão óbvios a não ser que você conheça os detalhes de implementação, o que matou parte da vantagem de ser uma abstração. Por isso muita gente pensa no termo como uma receita de bolo e não um fato questionável. O termo não é uma norma científica, é uma expressão marketeira.

Se isso fosse verdade então quase todas linguagens teriam ZCA. É verdade que C é uma linguagem que isso é bem verdade (não falarei de Assembly porque lá não tem abstrações que gerem uma camada extra de nada), mas não 100% verdade. Todas as outras tem porcentagens bem mais baixas, embora algumas mais que outras, caso de C++ e Rust, mas não em todos os mecanismos.

Se o termo fosse essa última citação então ele deveria ser Controllable Cost Abstraction ou algo parecido com isso.

## C comparado com C++ ou Rust

Alguns dirão que você não faria nada na mão mais eficiente que aquilo, atingindo o mesmo objetivo, já que o objetivo é ter algo mais fácil de usar. Isso até pode ser verdade, mas é uma abstração e tem um custo.

Pode dizer que você não é obrigado usar aquilo e só paga se usar, tem outra forma mais eficiente. Também é verdade, mas não pode dizer que aquele mecanismo é livre de custo, pode ainda dizer que a linguagem pode ser livre de custo, mas só é livre de verdade se programar como se fosse C.

Mesmo isso é um exagero porque o compilador de C++ gera um código ligeiramente mais pesado mesmo que só use mecanismos de C. É mínimo, mas não é zero.

Acontece o mesmo com Rust, embora em algumas coisas ela esteja mais próxima do C do que C++. Mas também tem abstrações menos poderosas, Rust vaza mais abstração que C++ (se você quiser pode vazar em C++ também, e se o fizer tende a obter mais eficiência em muitos casos).

Por isso que os testes de comparação de linguagens não ajudam muito, você pode escrever um código muito eficiente em Rust sem usar abstrações e um menos eficiente em C++ usando as abstrações.

## Exemplos

#### `string`

Um exemplo é a `string` do C++, bem poderosa e fácil de usar, mas não dá para dizer que ela é sempre livre de custos extras em relação ao que se usa em C. Ela costuma fazer uma alocação dinâmica que é bem cara sem você nem saber (nem sempre faz). E tem otimização que faz aumentar custo em outro ponto.

A maioria das implementações de C++ ocupa 24 bytes não importa o que use. Alguns acham que deveria ocupar 32 bytes. Com isso pequenas *strings* com até um certo tamanho cabem ali mesmo e tudo fica ótimo, a não ser pelo fato que sempre tem que analisar se é uma *string* curta antes de fazer alguma coisa. Se ela for grande ali tem o ponteiro para o local do *heap* onde de fato estará a *string*. Isso parece bom, tem ganhos interessantes, mas tem custos. Isso é uma boa abstração, mas não é de custo zero. É estranho, o tipo pode ser por valor ou referência. Se você tiver vários textos iguais curtos terá várias instâncias, mas se forem longos poderá ser o mesmo objeto. Uma simples referência pode ter 24 bytes? WTF! Coloca isso em um *array* e veja o estrago que faz. Nem Java ou C# ou linguagens de *script* costumam ser tão ineficientes nesse ponto específico.

E ela é muito usada em locais onde precisa calcular um *hash*, você não paga nada se não usar, mas se usar pagará um preço maior porque terá que calcular todas as vezes que precisar dele, uma indecência para uma linguagem que prima pela performance.

Pelo menos é assim na implementação padrão, se você não usá-la nada disso tem custo, pode fazer uma sua sem problemas e que não tenha os custos indesejados, mas também terá problemas para usá-la com toda biblioteca padrão que espera a *string* padrão.

Já ouviu falar que em computação, assim como na vida, (quase) tudo é *tradeoff*?

C# em 64 bits também ocupa 24 bytes no mínimo para uma *string* (sem contar o ponteiro no objeto original da(s) referência(s), e cresce rápido conforme vai adicionando caracteres. É ótima abstração, mas tem custo, exige sempre alocação dinâmica, mas se bobear, fora que não haver otimização para texto curto, ela é mais eficiente que C++.

Java chegou ter 40 bytes em 32bits, não sei como está hoje, mas isso é um absurdo, em muitos casos para armazenar 1 ou 2 caracteres (ficará maior).

C não tem nada desse custo, você decide onde quer alocar, embora alguns digam que nunca deveria alocar na *stack*, ou mesmo dentro de uma `struct` (alguns compiladores nem permitem), tudo ótimo, mas dá trabalho, causa erro, nem sempre o programador consegue a melhor eficiência, por exemplo ele pode armazenar como valor e em algum momento pode ter que copiar o dado que pode ser grande demais, para compensar, ou usar uma referência onde provoca lambança.

Sem falar no fato que tem que passar o tamanho junto com o texto para fazer certo e ser eficiente (não é do jeito que vemos por aí que [as pessoas usam `strlen()` para todo lado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), a falta de abstração pode gerar um custo extra absurdo). A concretude de C não a deixa livre de ter custos ruins.

Embora não precisasse de uma abstração para resolver isso, com a abstração fica mais agradável e menos propenso a erros, ou seja, não é a abstração que C++ criou que fez ser mais eficiente, é o mecanismo certo, a abstração é só uma capa que ajuda outra coisa.

Pra mim todas *strings* estão erradas em todas linguagens que eu conheço (muitas). Este é um tipo que depende de muitos cenários e cada um tem uma necessidade, se precisa manter o custo mais baixo com a melhor abstração *string* deveria ser um tipo concreto sempre abaixo de um tipo abstrato, e deveria ter diversas implementações. Em geral o pessoal considera isso um defeito da linguagem, mas só porque não tem o tipo abstrato geral que define o contrato básico do que uma *string* deve fazer (pode ter até uma hierarquia desses tipos abstratos), então sempre que não precisar de uma característica específica, aceita qualquer *string* (a maioria dos casos).

Isso não é sem custo porque, ou precisaria ser um tipo polimórfico que gera uma indireção extra, ou precisa ser um tipo parametrizado que gera várias versões de métodos que usem diferentes implementações de uma *string*.

#### Geração de código

Geração de código de alguma forma (*template*, macro, pré processador, ferramenta externa, "otimizadores") costuma ser uma faca de dois gumes, porque tende a gerar códigos mais rápidos por resolver muita coisa em tempo de compilação, mas o código costuma ficar maior, o que em alguns casos pode significar alguma perda de performance também, de uma outra forma.

Sem o mecanismo de geração de código de C++ ou Rust para conseguir certas eficiências é preciso escrever muito mais código, e redundante, o que pode gerar vários problemas, por isso as pessoas preferem pagar um preço de eficiência, pela falta de abstração.

#### Dependências

Em geral as bibliotecas das linguagens são muito dependentes de várias partes, então se usar uma função pode acabar puxando uma linha enorme de outras funções e você nem perceber, você paga um custo de carga disso mesmo sem usar de fato, só porque tinha dependência não usada.

Até C tem isso. Poucas pessoas sabem, mas se você usar uma função de uma biblioteca, ela vai inteira. Não precisa ser assim, mas todos compiladores organizam os objetos de forma que isso acontece de fato. Se não chamar não paga processamento, mas paga espaço no executável, que pode ou não se refletir em custo de memória (depende de como está organizado e da [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203928/101)), mas se separar função por função haverá outro custo, por isso algumas pessoas preferem fazer um arquivo fonte único (*amalgamação*) e assim não ter custos adicionais, até onde dá.

#### Tipo abstrato sem custo

Um exemplo contrário seria você criar um tipo que armazena e manipula temperatura. Em geral ele só encapsula um tipo concreto e não impõe custos adicionais, no fim dá na mesma se tivesse usando um tipo primitivo em termos de eficiência.

Ou quase isso, porque quando chamar alguns métodos deste tipo é possível que eles façam alguma coisa que você não faria na mão se fosse específico. É difícil fazer abstrações sem custo até mesmo do jeito mais básico. Tem hora que é bom usar de um jeito, tem hora que é melhor algo mais limpo e direto. Uma simples verificação de argumento válido já muda o custo. Sem a abstração você não precisa ter o custo todas as vezes, em alguns casos pode ir direto sem validar nada porque tem certeza da validade. Mas se precisar validar terá que escrever um código na mão antes de chamar a função desejada.

#### Custo da função

A própria função tem um custo extra só de chamar. Claro que pode haver alguma otimização e ela ser eliminada, deixando sem custo. Mas nem sempre a otimização do compilador consegue eliminar 100% do custo. E em alguns casos não compensa otimizar, você pagará o preço, e ele será mínimo, irrisório no todo, mas não será zero.

E tem otimizações que podem dar custo maior ainda, por isso o uso de um compilador bom é indicado quando deseja o máximo de performance. Hoje em dia é burrice tentar o máximo de otimização possível pra tudo. E o custo só de tentar costuma ser alto e não compensa. Você conviverá com algumas ineficiências. E claro, é raro ter um problema que precisa da última milha de desempenho.

Resolve todos os problemas da computação, certo? Mas nunca sem custo, a [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) é um custo inerente. Há casos que a indireção é indispensável, até em Assembly o mais otimizado possível tem que usar. Mas tem casos que só está lá por uma facilidade, esses casos são abstrações de custo **não zero**. E a função é só uma delas. E o não uso da indireção pode dificultar alguma outra otimização, então é complicado avaliar.

#### LINQ

C# tem LINQ, é legal, muitas linguagens copiaram, mas tem um belo custo de abstração embutido. Tem linguagem que consegue fazer algo mais eficiente igual ao LINQ sem custo de abstração, mas só nos métodos mais simples (não é impossível fazer em outros, mas precisa de uma análise absurda, talvez até usar IA).

Em Rust por exemplo isso `(0..1000).sum()` vira uma constante e realmente passa ter custo zero, em C ou Assembly você teria que abrir mão da abstração e fazer na mão a otimização. Em C# você normalmente pagará o custo de execução, em tese algo simples é assim, poderia fazer uma otimização fácil, mas em C não faz parte da filosofia da linguagem ir tão longe em um caso como este, a não ser que use uma macro para isso, mas não teria a mesma função que o LINQ tem.

#### *Garbage collector*

Como contraponto este é um caso que você quase sempre paga mesmo sem usar. Mais ou menos. Em certas linguagens realmente é sempre verdade, tem algumas que permitem desligá-lo e você fica por conta, é para raros cenários, mas tem como. Em C++ ou Rust você paga só se usar de fato e tende pagar só o que usa, ele é *opt-in*. Em Rust você paga só se usar o `Box` ou se usar o `Rc` ou o `Arc`, cada um com seu custo.

Mas como eu disse em outros pontos, isso sempre a custo do vazamento da abstração.

[image: A programming language is low level when its programs require attention to the irrelevant.]

## Comparando linguagens de alto nível

Linguagens de *script* ligam pouco pra tipagem, pra onde o dado está sendo alocado, se o acessa por valor ou referência, por isso elas são mais fáceis, está tudo abstraído e você paga por isso, e você não tem escolha, ter escolhas dificulta.

E isso gera mais custos do que as pessoas imaginam, todo dado acessado é um perigo em potencial, sempre precisa de um processamento complexo só para pegar o dado (alguns casos existem otimizações). Por exemplo, essas linguagens não costumam ter objetos mas sim estruturas de [dicionários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101) que se passam por objetos, isso é um custo em vários aspectos.

Java já optou por um caminho que você tem mais controles de tipo, de onde aloca, mas bem por cima. Não é igual C#, especialmente nas versões mais novas que o controle é muito maior, você pode não pagar certos custos se usar o mecanismo mais eficiente.

Em C++ e Rust isso vai mais longe e dá mais liberdade de escolha, eliminando boa parte dos custos, e como ela se compatibiliza com C, se optar por esse *subset* da linguagem pode ter menos custo ainda, só perdendo, só em alguns casos, para Assembly. Nem todas decisões são como você gostaria para um certo cenário.

Você poder abrir mão da abstração não indica que ela não tem custo, mas algumas pessoas acham que sim.

> É algo que o programador precisa ter conhecimento para usar ou é indiferente?

Sim, e não. Um bom programador que se preocupa com isso deve saber e idealmente ele deve pesquisar e ver se realmente está cumprido o que foi prometido, eu já disse que tem muito marketing nisso.

Se precisa muito espremer tudo o que for possível precisa entender todos os custos de todos os mecanismos que está usando e se dá para fazer na mão de um jeito melhor para alcançar o objetivo supremo da eficiência máxima. Nem tudo o que está fazendo precisa disto.

Mas quem tem que se preocupar mais é quem faz bibliotecas para outros usarem em um ambiente onde se preza pela *zero cost abstraction*. Se a sua biblioteca não tem custo zero nenhuma aplicação que usá-la, inclusive outras partes da biblioteca terá custo zero, é contaminante.

> Realmente é um ponto 100% positivo?

Até onde eu sei, ele em si, sim. Claro, se fizer certo, e se for verdadeiro e não ilusão, ou se ele existe em um ponto mas prejudica outro.

Ser ZCA em um ponto pode impedir ser em outro, vide o exemplo da `string` do C++ que eu falei. Note que os outros tem alguns custos para evitar certos custos. Mas sempre pode alegar que pode fazer como é no C e ter custo zero ou fazer um tipo seu onde você tem um custo só no que realmente usa. É verdade, mas isso vale para qualquer linguagem, em C# você pode criar seu tipo *string* com os compromissos que desejar, a diferença é que o tipo normal vai junto mesmo que não o use, embora isso será verdade em quase todas linguagens, só dá para abrir mão de um tipo tão presente se abrir mão de tudo o que a biblioteca padrão tem.

> Não há nenhum efeito indesejável na utilização da linguagem por possuir esse recurso?

De forma geral e clara não tem, mas a linguagem tende a ser um pouco mais complexa para atingir isso, não sei se é algo ruim, e mesmo que seja, ainda é algo que pode ser necessário por outros motivos.

A construção da biblioteca costuma ser bem mais complexa e o código interno costuma ser bem confuso por causa disto. Se não for um código tão confuso, ou a linguagem é boa demais, até pra ser verdade, ou não tem custo zero de fato.

Tem compiladores que fazem exceções na compilação quando sabe que ali precisa caprichar para ter um custo zero ou pelo menos mais baixo que o normal que ele faria. Isso nem sempre é bom, mas dá uma vantagem interessante, é uma forma de não criar complexidade na linguagem para tratar casos muito específicos. Um caso típico pode ser uma *string*, um tipo muito usado e que requer otimizações fora do normal, e que podem ser mais fáceis porque ele sabe em profundidade com o que está lidando.

Dá pra escrever muito mais sobre o assunto, quase cada frase abre porta para novas dúvidas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Conceptual.md).