# Como pesquisar por uma substring a partir de um offset em Rust?

Tags: string, rust, indexof

Como encontrar o índice do inicio de uma *substring* começando a partir de um determinado índice da *string*?

Em C++, por exemplo, o método [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find#Example) aceita um *offset* ou índice de por onde a busca deve começar.

Existe algo similar em Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se isso se enquadra ao que se chama de "idiomático", mas vejamos...

Basicamente, assumindo que queremos achar o índice de uma substring a partir de um determinado `offset`, poderíamos fazer assim:

```
let string = "ABC ABC ABC";
let offset = 3;

let idx = string
    .chars()
    .skip(offset)
    .collect::<String>()
    .find("ABC")
    .map(|n| n + offset);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92b38ad8f2a1a12368a78fda0c6773c8).</sup>

Basicamente, funciona da seguinte forma:

1. Criamos um iterador a partir dos caracteres da string (encadeamento com método `chars`).
2. A partir do iterador retornado por `chars`, **pulamos** o número de elementos correspondente ao offset (encadeamento `skip`).
3. A partir do restante do iterador, geramos uma nova String. Note que será *owned* e, portanto, representará alocação na *heap* (encadeamento `collect::<String>`).
4. A partir da string coletada anteriormente, utilizamos o método `find` para procurar o índice correspondente à substring procurada. Esse método retorna um `Option<usize>`, o que significa que retornará `None` quando a substring não for encontrada.
5. No caso da substring ser encontrada, precisaremos somar o *offset* que pulamos na etapa 2 ao índice retornado pelo método `find`. Para isso, utilizamos o método `map`, implementado por `Option`, que mapeia o valor no caso `Some` de acordo com a função passada. No caso de `None`, o mapeamento será ignorado e `map` simplesmente retornará o próprio `None`.

Pode parecer pouco performático, mas como o Rust é tão rigoroso com as chamadas [*Zero Cost Abstractions*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/437261/69296), suponho que diversas otimizações são feitas durante a fase intermediária do processo de compilação. No entanto, não fiz *benchmarks* para confirmar essa hipótese.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Mas uma dúvida, se eu usar o find numa subslice tipo `string[offset..].find`, isso evitaria a alocação?

Comment: Não terá a alocação, mas tenha em mente que, ao utilizar essa notação, você não estará iterando sobre os caracteres da string, mas sim sobre os bytes na codificação UTF-8. O caractere ``, por exemplo, tem 4 bytes. Já `á`, 2 bytes. Enquanto `a`, 1 byte. Além disso, ao utilizar o _slice_, você deve garantir que está indexando "intervalos válidos" em relação aos _bytes_... Enfim, é uma complicação danada. Por isso, nesse caso, creio que vale mais a pena utilizar o método `chars` (para garantir que estamos indexando sobre os caracteres, e não os bytes).

Comment: Veja [este playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b9ba26f04af096a2947623f39e47f4e) com um exemplo drástico para entender melhor o "problema". Veja as seções [§ 4.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices) e [§ 8.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#slicing-strings) do Livro para saber mais. E também tem a questão das [normalizações Unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/69296), o que pode afetar até mesmo o `chars`...

Comment: [Esta](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-get-a-substring-of-a-string/1351/16) e [esta](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-substring-function/24854/6) discussões podem ser úteis para mais informações sobre a indexação de _slices_ de strings também.

Comment: @suriyel, acabei pegando a oportunidade desse seu comentário para me aprofundar um pouco mais nesse assunto. Vou adicionar aqui mais uma referência de um outro bom artigo que encontrei: [Unicode String Models](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wuzzMOvKOJw93SWZAqoim1VUl9mloUxE0W6Ki_G23tw).